# Gnome-Shell freeze after resume from suspend

Tags: 14.04, gnome, suspend, power-management

I experience the following issue for now more than a month. After I wake up my notebook from suspend (usually opening the lid), I see the usual gnome-shell lockscreen prompt, where I enter my password.
In only ~20% of the cases, this works well and I can login normally and resume my work.

In the other ~80% of the cases the login process needs an awful lot of time or fails completely. If I can finally see my desktop, hotkeys do longer work (Fn+something as well as custom hotkeys to open a terminal etc), the icon bar on the top right shows that my laptop is on battery even though it is plugged in, random programs freeze after some time which is hard to specify and the whole system does not seem to run smoothly. Only a reboot can fix this.

I have no idea how to debug this and how to find relevant log files, which might help. I found this [reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/debian/comments/3gz1rl/gnome3_freezes_during_unlock_after_long_periods/?st=itpg7kux&sh=b11f47f1), where similar issues are described. The solution there was to unmount any network drives. As I don't have any, this is not the solution.

I cannot directly say when this problem started, but it must have started after some updates, because for ~2 years I had no such problem with suspend on my machine.

Output of `uname -a` :

```
Linux myLaptop 3.16.0-77-generic #99~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jun 28 19:17:10 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: I've filed a bug report here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdm3/+bug/1741839 Please confirm that the bug affects you to draw more attention to the bug